# How to calculate the sum of a column by individual category separately?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need some help

I need to calculate the total hours of each employee and also show all the dates of each employee in a same table.

My Table is like below-

| Employee | Date | hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rohit | 06-03-2022 | 9 |
| Rohit | 07-03-2022 | 8 |
| Rohit | 08-03-2022 | 9 |
| Rohit | 09-03-2022 | 9 |
| Rohit | 10-03-2022 | 10 |
| Rohit | 11-03-2022 | 8 |
| Rohit | 12-03-2022 | 8 |
| Rohit | 06-03-2022 | 7 |
| Raj | 07-03-2022 | 8 |
| Raj | 08-03-2022 | 4 |
| Raj | 09-03-2022 | 3 |
| Raj | 10-03-2022 | 5 |
| Raj | 11-03-2022 | 8 |
| Raj | 12-03-2022 | 8 |

The output should be like this

| Employee | Date | hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rohit | 06-03-2022 | 9 |
| Rohit | 07-03-2022 | 8 |
| Rohit | 08-03-2022 | 9 |
| Rohit | 09-03-2022 | 9 |
| Rohit | 10-03-2022 | 10 |
| Rohit | 11-03-2022 | 8 |
| Rohit | 12-03-2022 | 8 |
| Rohit | 06-03-2022 | 7 |
| **Total** |  | **68** |
| Raj | 07-03-2022 | 8 |
| Raj | 08-03-2022 | 4 |
| Raj | 09-03-2022 | 3 |
| Raj | 10-03-2022 | 5 |
| Raj | 11-03-2022 | 8 |
| Raj | 12-03-2022 | 8 |
| **Total** |  | **36** |

Comment: Please include a) the expected output and b) the query you may have already tried to solve your problem.

Comment: Look into `GROUPING_SETS`.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen I have edited the question with my output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUPING SETS` for this

```sql
SELECT
  Employee = CASE WHEN GROUPING(t.Date) = 0 THEN t.Employee ELSE 'Total' END,
  t.Date,
  hours = SUM(t.hours)
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (Employee, Date),
    (Employee)
);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=48b52ac72ce43f88a976c17b86fd75d4)

> The `GROUPING()` function tells you whether a column has been aggregated for that row